# mysql two table query problem

Tags: mysql

```
a table
a_id a_value
 1   text1
 2   test2

b table
b_id b_num a_id 
 1    5     1
 2    7     1
 3    2     1
 4    7     2
 5    56    2
```

Results base a table (edited)

**a_id:1 a_value:text1 total:3 records**

**a_id:2 a_value:text2 total:2 records**

How can get this format in sql?

**query a table and add a field(total) count b.a_id = a.a_id in table b**

thank you..

Comment: Based on your data in table b, how do you get the follwoing `a_id:2 total:2 records`?

Comment: How did you get 3 and 2 total records? Are you sure the b table data is correct?

Comment: Are you trying to get the count of `b_id`s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
SELECT a.a_id AS id, a.a_value AS value, (SELECT count(b.b_id) AS count FROM b WHERE (b.a_id = a.a_id)) AS total FROM a GROUP BY a.a_id
```

Then the result for your example using the data from tables **a** and **b**:

```
**id    value     total** 

  1     text1     3

  2     text2     2
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you have an error in your b table, so I will assume what you call `b_id` is actually `a_id`, or your results would be wrong

Anyway you could use:

```
SELECT COUNT(b.a_id) AS total FROM b GROUP BY (SELECT a.a_id FROM a)
   ORDER BY b.a_id
```

Answer (score 0):

The updated query based on changes to the question

```
SELECT a_id, a_value, x.total
FROM a
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT b.a_id, COUNT(1) AS total 
    FROM b 
    GROUP BY (b.a_id)) X
ON a.a_id = x.a_id
ORDER BY a.a_id
```

Comment: @LNXA - I have updated the query. I think this should work as per the updated question